# Can't convert molecule to fingerprint with rdkit

Tags: python, rdkit, fingerprinting

I'm trying to convert molecular smiles into fingerprints using `rdkit`. I have two smiles:
Nc1cccc(N)n1 and Nc1cc(CSc2ccc(O)cc2)cc(N)n1. The first one was expanded into the second one. In other words, the second molecule contains the first one in its structure.

What I did was use rdkit to remove the common part to obtain smiles of a fragment that differs (CSC1=CC=C(O)C=C1 in kekulized form). I'm trying to convert that fragment into a molecule and then to a fingerprint to calculate similarity with a reference molecule.

[Desired transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuxPj.png)

But I get an error: 'Can't kekulize atoms' with indices of those atoms. This is strange to me because all the smiles (the two input smiles and the resulting fragment smiles) can be easily visualized using MarvinSketch or Chemdraw (software for drawing molecules). I even had Marvin kekulize the fragment smiles and tried making a molecule from that but I still get the same error. Here is my code for removing the fragment:

```
def remove_initial_fragment(mol_smiles, fragment_smiles):
    mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(mol_smiles) #creates molecule from the longer smiles
    fragment = Chem.MolFromSmiles(fragment_smiles) #the molecule I want to remove

    rm = AllChem.DeleteSubstructs(mol, fragment) #creates new molecule

    return Chem.MolToSmiles(rm) #converts the mol I want back into smiles

smiles_frags = [remove_initial_fragment(x, fragment_smiles) for x in smiles]
mols_frags = [Chem.MolFromSmiles(x) for x in smiles_frags]
```

In my case, the 'fragment_smiles' is the same for all selected smiles.
But then I get an error when trying to convert molecules from the 'mols_frags' list into fingerprints:

```
MFP_2 = [AllChem.GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect(x, 2) for x in mols_frags]
```

I tried looking online for answers but nothing really helped. I even tried to create kekulized smiles separately and passing them directly as input for creating the fingerprints but I still get the same error.

It's super weird to me because when I try to do the same process with the same code for one set of smiles (fragment, longer smiles, resulting smiles), it works without a problem and I can create the fingerprint without any error. But it seems to me that once I input the smiles/molecules as a list, I get the error. Any idea why this could be? Or do you see any error in my code that I'm unaware of?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you have `fragment_smiles = 'Nc1cccc(N)n1'` and a `list` like
`smiles = ['Nc1cc(CSc2ccc(O)cc2)cc(N)n1', 'Nc1cc(COc2ccc(O)cc2)cc(N)n1']`. This works for me.
Are all SMILES in your `list` correct? The RDKit is very strict about reading SMILES.

Comment: Yes, I have `fragment_smiles` and `list` that you described. The problem isn't really in removing the `fragment_smiles`. That executes nicely. But the smiles I obtain this way give an error when trying to make fingerprints out of them. The `fragment_smiles` and smiles in the `list` are all correct because I used them to create fingerprints of the whole, unchanged, molecules and that worked without a problem.
And when I try to take one smiles from the `list`, remove the fragment from it and use the resulting smiles to create a fingerprint it works. But when I try to automate it, it gives error

Comment: I have no problem with the fingerprints from `MFP_2 = [Chem.GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect(x, 2) for x in mols_frags]`.
It seems that one of your `smiles_frags` / `mols_frags` is corrupt.

Comment: I think you're right. I tinkered with this more and I think I'm seeing one smiles is indeed corrupted. And because I pass everything as lists, the script encounters the corrupted smiles and stops completely. I'm working on fixing it now. Now how do I accept your answer as a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `fragment_smiles = 'Nc1cccc(N)n1'` and a `list` like `smiles = ['Nc1cc(CSc2ccc(O)cc2)cc(N)n1', 'Nc1cc(COc2ccc(O)cc2)cc(N)n1']`. I have no problem getting a fingerprint.

It looks as if, after deleting the substructure, there are some smiles_frags that are not correct SMILES.

To prove wich SMILES in the `list` gives the problem you can use

```
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem as Chem

fragment = Chem.MolFromSmiles('Nc1cccc(N)n1')

smiles = ['Nc1cc(CSc2ccc(O)cc2)cc(N)n1', 'Nc1cc(COc2ccc(O)cc2)cc(N)n1', 'CC1=CC=Cc2c(N)nc(N)cc12']

for smi in smiles:
    try:
        mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smi)
        f1 = Chem.DeleteSubstructs(mol, fragment)
        f2 = Chem.MolFromSmiles(Chem.MolToSmiles(f1))
        fp = Chem.GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect(f2, 2)
    except:
        print('SMILES:', smi)
        f = Chem.DeleteSubstructs(mol, fragment)
        print('smiles_frag:', Chem.MolToSmiles(f1))
```

This will give:

```
SMILES: CC1=CC=Cc2c(N)nc(N)cc12
smiles_frag: ccccC
```

Comment: Thank you. You were right. For some reason, some SMILES weren't correct after deleting substructure. I already found them and had my script skip them for the time being before I figure out why they are wrong and how to fix them.